# wordpress wp-plugin as referrer in non wordpress server

Tags: wordpress, logging

I have recently found some strange logs on my webserver (something about wordpress):

```
[Wed Nov 15 19:44:28 2017] [error] [client 209.90.225.243] File does not exist: /path/to/vhosts/docroot/wp-content, referer: http://my.domain/wp-content/plugins/revslider/temp/
[Mon Nov 13 19:05:51 2017] [error] [client 209.90.225.243] File does not exist: /path/to/vhosts/docroot/wp-content, referer: http://my.domain/wp-content/themes/famous/style.css
[Sat Nov 11 22:21:38 2017] [error] [client 209.90.225.243] File does not exist: /path/to/vhosts/docroot/wp-content, referer: http://my.domain/wp-content/plugins/complete-gallery-manager/frames/upload-images.php
```

The main problem is that I don't have a wordpress installed in the virtual-host where I found the these errors. On the same server, there are other intallations of word-press that I don't have access to.

Does anybody know why I'm seeing these logs messages? The referer page doesn't exist on my server, but it's easy to change in a http request made from scratch.

Could it be a random attack?

Comment: format your post.... this is a mess to read.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, I usually search for questions so and I'm not very familiar with the question UI. Next time I'll format properly.

Comment: @FabioSun not a problem! Glad to help :)